# save api response as .html in angular 6

Tags: angular, laravel-5.8

I am creating an app which uses angular 6 in frontend and laravel 5.8 as backend. One api returns response as html code that should be saved in html format file and open in browser. How can I do this in angular 6.

I tried below code, but not working

```
<div class='html-redirect' innerHTML="{{data}}"></div>
```

I am new to angular.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<div class="html-redirect" [innerHTML]="data"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the HTML string through [DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml()](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrusthtml) before outputting it in the template. Otherwise Angular will encode the untrusted HTML.

Comment: I am trying this, but my response contains javascript functions which suppose to redirect bank payment url, which is not happening. I tried @qwerty's solution also, but no help.

Comment: Please add more context to the question then. :) You could try running it through  `bypassSecurityTrustScript()` as well, but I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve even makes sense. Why are you loading scripts that way?

Comment: I hit a third party api which returns me html code in xml, I need to open that html code in browser which has javascript functions of redirections. basically that html page is payment page of bank. I don't know how to do that. :(

Comment: We won't be able to help you without knowing more about the API. But why don't you open it in a separate tab (just add a link to the API page)?

Comment: I solve this by using `document.write(res.data);` which redirects me to desired third party web page. Thanks for your time and help. :)